# Android game developing - dynamic bounds definition

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am currently developing a game for android using libgdx library .
Lets say we have a lizard, now the user creates paths by sliding fingers on the screen, on which the lizard can walk on.
The question is , how do restrict the lizard to walk on only where the finger touched the screen( on the path - between the bounds).

```
public class Block {

static final float SIZE = 1f;
Vector2 position = new Vector2();
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();

public Block(Vector2 pos) {

    this.position = pos;
    this.bounds.width = SIZE;
    this.bounds.height = SIZE;
}
}
```

In this example we can see a block, the bounds of the block is a rectangle on which the lizard can walk on.

how do I make some similar bounds only using a circle?

Here is what i got so far:
I have created a doubled layer bitmap that overlap each other. When the user touches the screen , he erases the first bitmap reveling the second bitmap underneath the first one ( only the part where the user touched get removed).

here is the function that erases the first bitmap.

```
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

        c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 40, pTouch);
        Paint new_paint = new Paint(/*Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG*/);
        new_paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_ATOP));
       //new_paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, new_paint);
    }
```

Notice#
the bitmap is removed using a circle shape.

It would be great if i could add to the circle that's removing the bitmap, a property of bound, on which the lizard can walk on.
Any ideas?

Comment: Format your code so we can read it

Answer (score 2):

u should update the cordinates of bounds as per the lizard position

```
bounds.x=position.x; 
bounds.y=position.y;
```

So that your bounds follow the lizard

Also instead of using recatangle for bounds try to use

```
 sprite.getBoundingRectangle()
```

this method gives u the exact rectangular bounds of the image so no need to maintain bounds. 
Provided you use AtlasSprite or Sprite for your image.

Comment: for drag logic check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392323/dragging-in-libgdx-on-spritebatch

Comment: Thanks, but i don't need a rectangle bounds, what i need are bounds that are not a straight line, they are dynamic and created by the user.It would be ideal if there was a similar "block" type that i can create only using circle.

Answer (score 1):

I shared my game [Bomberman](https://github.com/Suvitruf/libgdx/tree/master/NES%20Bomberman) early. You can find code you needed in [GameScreen](https://github.com/Suvitruf/libgdx/blob/master/NES%20Bomberman/src/suvitruf/classic/bomberman/screens/GameScreen.java) class

p.s. also you can find different interesting samples of LibGDX usage [here](https://github.com/Suvitruf/libgdx)

Comment: Thanks, but could u point me to a more specific part of the code, where you actually implement a dynamic bounds.

Comment: @user1936506 in touchDown, touchUp and touchDragged events in GameScreen we catch touches, and say to controller aboit it. In next render time in WorldController.java in update() method we move elements of the world using that information from GameScreen.